# Why, when i scale polygons my light intensity changes?

Tags: java, opengl, lighting, opengl-compat

I need to easy change my polygon scale in OpenGL project, but for some reason, the light intensity is directly proportional to the size of the polygons.

I tried to move light direction to different places. Change light intensity and div normal vectors on scaler, but it doesn't help.

In my Code `scaler` mean polygon compression => if `scaler = 2`
, `poly` become 0.5 of size

Vertices coords:

```
verticesMatrix[i][k] = new Vector3f((float) (i - cellCount / 2) / scaler, 
                      (float) 0, (float) (k - cellCount / 2) / scaler);
```

Calc normals:

```
 public void calcNormal(Vector3f s1, Vector3f s2, Vector3f s3) {
        Vector3f a = new Vector3f(s2.x - s1.x, s2.y - s1.y, s2.z - s1.z);
        Vector3f b = new Vector3f(s3.x - s2.x, s3.y - s2.y, s3.z - s2.z);
        Vector3f normal = new Vector3f(a.y * b.z - a.z * b.y, a.z * b.x - a.x 
        * b.z, a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x);
        glNormal3f(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);
    }
```

Light setup:

```
private static float[] lightPosition = {-2.19f, 100.36f, 11.45f, 1f};

 private static void setUpLighting() {
        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
        glLightModel(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, 
        BufferTools.asFlippedFloatBuffer(new float[]{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1f}));
        glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, 
        BufferTools.asFlippedFloatBuffer(lightPosition));
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glCullFace(GL_BACK);
        glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
        glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE);
    }
```

I need to have same light using different scaler. I don't know how it can influence on light, because i checked all code, and i don't use scaler with light. Result image: https://yadi.sk/i/kxQLvRSTP7LYVA

Comment: `scaler` affects coordinates of the vertices. A closer light (`lightPosition` remains unchanged) to these coords changes the intensity because it's 'point-light' not 'directional light' .See usage of `glLight`

Comment: @genpfault Why did you delete your answer? Probably you are right. I think this was a good catch.

Comment: Does `calcNormal()` actually emit unit-length normals?  It looks like it's just a cross-product, not seeing any attempt at (re)normalization.  Are the inputs always unit-length?

Comment: @Ripi2 The light is calculated per vertex ([Gouraud shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading)). The diffus part is the dot product of the normal vector and the light vector. So the light intensity depends on angle of the normal vector to the light vector, but not on the distance of the vertex coordinate to the position of the light source. For a distance dependency the [`*ATTENUATION`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es1.1/xhtml/glLight.xml) parameters have to be set (changed).

Comment: @Rabbid76 I admit I'm quite clumsy with OGL 1.1. But attenuation is taken into account for *w != 0*. as stated at [glLight doc](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLight.xml) (go down to GL_POSITION)

Comment: @Ripi2 But the default parameters (1, 0, 0) "disable" the attenuation. - the attenuation factor is constant 1 and the distance dependent factors are 0.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Right. But that's not the case for the OP, he defines `lightPosition`.

Comment: @Ripi2 Please read the specification ... That is not a guess, I know this very well.

Comment: Thanks, i really forgot to normalize my normals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to normolize normal like this:

```
public void calcNormal(Vector3f s1, Vector3f s2, Vector3f s3) {
        Vector3f a = new Vector3f(s2.x - s1.x, s2.y - s1.y, s2.z - s1.z);
        Vector3f b = new Vector3f(s3.x - s2.x, s3.y - s2.y, s3.z - s2.z);
        Vector3f normal = new Vector3f(a.y * b.z - a.z * b.y, a.z * b.x - a.x * b.z, a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x);
        float length = (float)Math.pow(normal.x * normal.x + normal.y * normal.y + normal.z * normal.z, 0.5f); 
        glNormal3f(normal.x / length, normal.y / length, normal.z / length);
    }
```